# Passing const variable value to another js file

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I'm new in React FrontEnd development . I have a list of products and I'm trying to display the product details I could not get the ID of the chosen product in my slug.js file which is the file that contains my product details's JSX

This is my ProductCard and I can retrieve the product's ID from this page and I could not send it to the other page which is my slug.js that contains my product's details's JFX any help is appreciated

I want to pass myChosenProduct const value to the parameter of slug.js file

```
export default function ProductCard({ data, label }) {
  const productData = {
    id: data.id,
    product_name: data.product_name,
    description: data.description,
    color: data.color,
    generalDescription: data.generalDescription,
    packageContent: data.packageContent,
    warranty: data.warranty,
    comments: data.comments,
    height: data.height,
    width: data.width,
    depth: data.depth,
    weight: data.weight,
    image: data.image,
    price: data.price,
    rating: data.rating,
    quantity: 1,
    sku: "032319DMJ",
    category: data.category,
  };

  return (
    
    <div className={styles.item}>
      <Link href={`products/product/${productData.id}`}>
        <a className={styles.productLink}>
          <FetchImage
            src={productData.image}
            alt={productData.product_name}
            width={240}
            height={160}
            objectFit="contain"
          />
          <h2 className={styles.productTitle}>
            {label ? <span className={styles.label}>{label}</span> : ""}
            {productData.product_name}
          </h2>
        </a>
      </Link>
      <div className={styles.itemContent}>
        <div className={styles.itemPrice}>
          <p>{convertFloatToCurrency(productData.price)}</p>
          <Link href={`/produto/${productData.id}`}
           to={{
           pathname: "/produto/${productData.id}",
           state: productData.id // your data array of objects
          }}

          >
         
            <a>
            
              <RedButton onClick={() => {{saveProductID(productData.id)}
                
              { console.log(productData.id);

                const myCHosenProduct= getProductById(productData.id);
                console.log(myCHosenProduct);}

  }} style={{ width: "100%" }}>Ver mais</RedButton>
              
            
            </a>
          </Link>

        </div>
        <div className={styles.rating}>
          <RatingStars value={productData.rating} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  );
  
  
}
```

this is my slug.js file :

```
export default function Produto({ productData, data }) {
//HERE I want to get myChosenProduct value in Pruduto parameter or in this file it doesn't matter So I can display my product's details

  return (
    <div className={styles.productContainer}>
      
      
      <div className="container">
        <Breadcrumbs />

        <div className={styles.content}>
          <section className={styles.productInfo}>  
         { /* 3) PROBLEM MAYBE RELATED TO THE 1ST ONE  <ProductGallery images={images}/> */ }
              <div>
              <div className={styles.infoWrapper}>
              <div className={styles.rating}>
                <div className={styles.stars}>
               { /* SEEMS LIKE EVERYTHING RELATED TO PRODUCTDATA HAS PROBLEMS   <RatingStars value={productData.rating} size={16} /> */}
                  <span>
                   
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <p>
                    Vendido e entregue por <span>Mega Atacado</span>
                  </p>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>

              <div className={styles.productName}>
               { /*<h1>{productData.product_name}</h1> */}
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>

       

        


          <InformacoesProduto style={{ marginTop: "2.5rem" }} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please write a minimal, reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: what about now man all good ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ReactJs props are passed from the parent component to its child component.
You have to check what "productData" you've passed to the component Produto when your calling it in his parent.